# СУММЕСЛИМН и Arrayformula

Tags: google-spreadsheet, суммирование

Не работает `СУММЕСЛИМН` с Arrayformula.
Отдельно работает, а если вставляю в Arrayformula, выводит 0,00 руб.

Нужно просуммировать суммы по нескольким условиям, в том числе за период, введя условие больше или равно заданной даты, и меньше или равно заданной даты.
И это суммирование необходимо продлить на динамическое количество строк.

Так не работает:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ЕСЛИ($A$8:$A<>""; СУММЕСЛИМН('Мененджер 1'!$G$3:$G;'Мененджер 1'!$C$3:$C;$A$8:$A;'Мененджер 1'!$A$3:$A;">="&$B$1;'Мененджер 1'!$A$3:$A;"<="&$C$1);""))
```

Результат всегда 0,00 руб.

А так работает:

```
СУММЕСЛИМН('Мененджер 1'!$G$3:$G;'Мененджер 1'!$C$3:$C;$A$8:$A;'Мененджер 1'!$A$3:$A;">="&$B$1;'Мененджер 1'!$A$3:$A;"<="&$C$1)
```

Comment: Может есть вариант, как внутри Arrayformula просуммировать продажи по нескольким условиям за выбранный период без Суммесимн?

Comment: Добавьте Таблицу с примером данных.